# Parsing a DateTime in a time-zone

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I have a date-time from Los_Angeles. The daylight saving applies when possible. I'm trying to convert that date-time into a timestamp, but I don't seem to understand the Java 8 DateTime API. The following snippet returns `1238112000` (which is the correct date if it was specified in UTC). What should I change to show `1238137200` instead?

```
String date = "March 27, 2009 00:00:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.
                             ofPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).
                             withZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By parsing the date into a `LocalDateTime`, you are ignoring the timezone information from the formatter. You should use a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = "March 27, 2009 00:00:00";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
                         .withZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
    long second = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, formatter).toEpochSecond();
    System.out.println(second); // prints "1238137200"
}
```

On the returned instance, you can then call [`toEpochSecond()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toEpochSecond--).

Comment: @Pillar 1.8.0_74. Did you take all of the code? You shouldn't have that error.

Comment: Eclipse was actually running 1.8.0_05. Probably some leftover bug, maybe [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8041360).